# How to override a bundle in OroCrm

Tags: symfony, overriding, orocrm

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to override a specific class of a bundle.
The class I'd like to override is:

Oro\Bundle\MagentoBundle\Entity\Repository\CustomerRepository

To do so, I created my bundle

```
namespace Kiwee\Bundle\MnhBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MnhMagentoBundle extends Bundle {

    public function getParent() {
        return 'OroMagentoBundle';
    }
}
```

And I added the bundles.yml

```
bundles:
    - Kiwee\Bundle\MnhBundle\MnhMagentoBundle
```

So far, so good.. the bundle is loaded. 
Now, it seems I can't find any working example about how to override the class mentioned above.

I tried creating a file with the same relative path as the class I'd like to override, but it doesn't work.

```
namespace Kiwee\Bundle\MnhBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Oro\Bundle\MagentoBundle\Entity\Repository\CustomerRepository as BaseCustomerRepository;

class CustomerRepository extends BaseCustomerRepository
{
    public function calculateLifetimeValue(Customer $customer)
    {
        // [... here is my custom logic for this method ...]

    }
}
```

The first problem I have is that "Customer" is not the same type as in the original class.
The second is that, even fixing it by declaring the full class path, this method is never used while the original is.
Any hint?

Thank you very much

Comment: Take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623089/symfony2-how-to-override-a-specific-class-of-a-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Just override it as a regular doctrine repository.
See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37486268/2119164 it should resolve your issue.